# Why can't pgadmin connect to the server but I can get in using the command line?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When I try to use pgadmin I keep getting authentication errors.  I am using my own account and my login password.

The following does work:

```
$  sudo -u postgres createuser -s $USER
$ createdb md3
$ psql -d md3

psql (9.1.3)
Type "help" for help.

md3=#
```

However I then get this error in the pgadmin GUI:

[image]

Perhaps I should be using root or the postgres user?

Comment: Can you connect in the command line adding the option `-h localhost`? It could be that you need to configure remote access: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login in pgadmin as postgres user and check if the user "durrantm" exist and if he can login (there should be a checkbox in the privilege tab)